# Change package-private variable to private in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I want to change all variables and methods with default access modifiers to private only if its possible (If the variable is not been accessed outside class).
e.g

```
String test = null;

void setTest(String s) {
    this.test = s;
}
```

If abovementioned method and variable are not accessed outside class, is there a way to make them `private`? I can't do it manually, I'm working on a huge code base and it contains around a million of similar issues.

Please do mention if similar thing is possible with Intellij community edition.

Comment: See this  may it will help you .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328926/automatically-change-public-to-private-java

Comment: If i follow the approach mentioned in the link, It will take a lot of time as this is a code of millions of line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264880/is-that-possible-to-make-member-variables-automatically-private-in-eclipse

Comment: How this is helping us with the code which is already been written?

Comment: idea is that may eclipse give you facility to create your own template and apply it in your code that you have to get how can you write such template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what i wanted but following plugin can help us in it.

http://www.ucdetector.org/faq.html